Frequent failures of HDDs running Ubuntu!
Over the years, I have been using dual boot with 2 separate HDDs, with one running Windows and the other running Ubuntu. However, I have been experiencing more frequent HDD failures on HDDs running Ubuntu, regardless of the age of the HDD. I have so far replaced maybe 4 HDDs over the past decade or so, while the HDD running Windows is still running strong. Please note that I do not use Ubuntu as often. I had a recent HDD failure now, where the HDD is not getting detected at all even on Windows system, which is what generally happens to my HDDs. My experience over the years has made me wonder if somehow Ubuntu is causing my HDD failures.

The main reasons for hard drive failure are:
Disk head damage.
Controller PCB failure.
Head jams.
Motor failure.

A mechanical hard drive is based on a metal platter that spins at very high speeds. To write data, a head moves along the platter as it spins. Once it has found the right position, it carries out the reading or writing process. Any damage to the platters or the disk head can cause it to move outside these small margins, rendering the hard drive unusable. Objects falling on it, high or low voltage spikes can render it completely unusable, and the head can also hit the platter.
A hard drive has a small electronic circuit (PCB), right where its connectors are located, which has the necessary components to receive requests for reading/writing blocks of data from the computer and deliver them, as well as managing the operation of the disk. It is basically a CPU programmed to govern the operation and communicate with the PC and contains a cache chip, a BIOS for the initial start-up of the disk and capacitors, diodes, etc., like a microcomputer inside the hard drive itself, with so many components, a single failure with one of them can be fatal.
Head jams after a long period of non-use of the hard drive occur when the head mechanism becomes blocked and immobile, so that no data can be read.
The least common failure is the one caused by the motor, which is only responsible 1% of the time, since they use very good bearings, such as fluid dynamic bearings, and can be running for very long periods of time.
An SSD has no mechanical parts, the most common reason for this is wear and tear on the NAND memory.
The big problem with NAND memory used in SSDs is that they have a limited number of writes. In each of their cells, we can only write a certain number of times, until the cell is completely unusable.
This is not a write limit that is easily reached. In normal user use, it can happen, for example, after 10 years of use. SSD manufacturers are aware of this, so they impose a write limit on the SSD after which it remains in read-only mode, in order to be able to read that data safely and avoid loss.
It is also possible that a PCB failure occurs on these drives.
While a long period of non-use is not problematic as it is with mechanical hard drives, on an SSD, it can cause data to be erased.
Operating systems use file systems, structures for organizing and managing files on a storage device such as a hard drive, solid-state drive (SSD), or USB flash drive. The system defines how data is stored, accessed, and organized on the storage device. Different file systems have different characteristics, often specific to certain operating systems or devices. While they can cause data loss due to their own defects, they do not harm the storage devices.
